BitBlt and Direct3D for Screenshots C#
I'm working on a program to capture screenshots of windows from a window handle. I start by taking the screen shot using BitBlt, and if that fails when the window is using accelerated graphics, I switch to using Direct3D.
For reference, here's the BitBlt code:
private Bitmap BitBltWindow(Rectangle rect, IntPtr window)
{
    const uint srcCopy = 0x00CC0020;

    IntPtr hWndDc = GetDC(window);
    IntPtr hMemDc = CreateCompatibleDC(hWndDc);
    IntPtr hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWndDc, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    SelectObject(hMemDc, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hMemDc, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height, hWndDc, 0, 0, srcCopy);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(window, hWndDc);
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hMemDc);
    DeleteDC(hWndDc);

    return bitmap;
}

And here is my method to detect if it is empty:
private bool IsBitmapBlack(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int rowSize = bmpData.Stride < 0 ? -bmpData.Stride : bmpData.Stride;
    
    // Scanning for non-zero bytes
    bool allBlack = true;
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
        byte[] pixels = new byte[rowSize];
        Marshal.Copy(IntPtr.Add(ptr, y * bmpData.Stride), pixels, 0, rowSize);
        
        if(pixels.Max() > 0)
        {
            allBlack = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return allBlack;
}

My question is around how I'm detecting whether BitBlt failed or not. In windows like Chrome, the call to BitBlt just returns a blank bitmap, this is easy to detect and I switch to Direct3D. But in windows like Visual Studio 2022, it seems to use a mixture of graphics, so the bitmap returned is non-blank but has bits missing like so:

Whereas the same recording from Direct3D surface looks like this:

Does anyone know of a Windows API call I can use to detect if the window uses any amount of accelerated graphics?

Maybe Chrome is the problem and / or what is the "windows pointer" pointing to in each case. VS is a WPF app last I heard. Which method is or is not WPF aware; and / or does it need to be.

BitBlt only works on non-accelerated graphics, i.e it just reads the image from the device memory. So it doesn’t work on Chrome. Direct3D can read memory from the GPU, and the device memory, so works on any window I’ve tested so far. The pointer to the device context is non-zero in all cases, it’s just that there is no image to capture from the memory when there is accelerated graphics. What I want to know is if I can detect whether the window is using accelerated graphics.

After posting the question I decided to pursue looking at the process to see if I could detect if the loaded modules included any known as Direct3D. I wrote this off as a bad experiment, getting the list of modules was easy enough and it worked on some windows, but it didn't work on all windows I tried this on. e.g. Chrome.
I've settled on adjusting my IsBitmapBlack method into a method which detects if the window is part black. This gets around the issue of Visual Studio which has bits missing.
The new method now looks like this:
private bool IsBitmapPartBlack(Bitmap bmp)
{
    int height = bmp.Height;
    int width = bmp.Width;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int rowSize = bmpData.Stride < 0 ? -bmpData.Stride : bmpData.Stride;
        
    // Scanning for non-zero bytes
    bool partBlack = false;
    int blackRowCount = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        byte[] pixels = new byte[rowSize];
        Marshal.Copy(IntPtr.Add(ptr, y * bmpData.Stride), pixels, 0, rowSize);

        if (pixels.FirstOrDefault(pixel => pixel > 0) == 0)
        { 
            blackRowCount++;
            if (blackRowCount >= height * .01)  // If 1% of the bitmap rows are black then treat the image as part black
            {
                partBlack = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return partBlack;
}

